# Getting error in case using JRImageLoader.loadAwtImageFromBytes method for loading image

Tags: java, image, jasper-reports

I'm using JasperSoft Studio 6.8.0 and I've a struggling error:

I've a `logo` property of my Java class `EnvParameter`.

this property is a `byte[]`

I pass my Java class to Jasper Studio, so I try to load the image inside logo property as follow:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadAwtImageFromBytes($P{EnvParameter}.logo)
```

**EDIT**

I've also tried with

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadAwtImageFromBytes($P{EnvParameter}.getLogo())
```

But I have this error at runtime (compile it's OK):

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error
>   evaluating expression for source text:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadAwtImageFromBytes($P{EnvParameter}.logo)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.handleEvaluationException(JREvaluator.java:284)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.GroovyEvaluator.handleEvaluationException(GroovyEvaluator.java:98)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:316)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:672)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:640)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:1169)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:466)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:440)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:383)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:548)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillTitle(JRVerticalFiller.java:323)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:150)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:615)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:814)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:61)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:221)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadAwtImageFromBytes()
>   is applicable for argument types: ([B) values: [[-119, 80, 78, 71, 13,
>   10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, ...]] Possible solutions:
>   loadAwtImageFromBytes([B)     at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1518)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1504)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:52)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
>     at
>   rptVTitolo_1558437271760_434544.evaluate(calculator_rptVTitolo_1558437271760_434544:203)
>     at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:302)
>     ... 17 common frames omitted mag 21, 2019 1:17:36 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is wrong?

Looks like you are using wrong method for loading image.
The class *JRImageLoader* was changed during moving to *6.x* version of engine and there is no ***static*** method *loadAwtImageFromBytes(bytep[])* at this class at new versions of *JasperReports* (I believe that it was there at *JR 5.5.0*).

#### Working example

You can try this small example.

Small Bean for testing:

```
package ru.alex.model;

public class MyBean {

    private byte[] logo;

    public byte[] getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }

    public void setLogo(byte[] logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }
}
```

The template (*jrxml* file) is very simple (I'm using JasperReports 6.4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ImageExample" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="mybean" class="ru.alex.model.MyBean" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <title>
        <band height="72">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="200" y="10" width="50" height="50"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.getInstance(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance()).loadAwtImageFromBytes($P{mybean}.getLogo())]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

I used [*JRImageLoader.loadAwtImageFromBytes(byte[])*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRImageLoader.html#loadAwtImageFromBytes-byte:A-) method for loading image from bytes array. As you can see we need to get instance of *JRImageLoader* first - I used default context using this code: `JRImageLoader.getInstance(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance())`.

The code for generating report is simple as usual:

```
JasperReport jasperReport;
try (InputStream inputStream = JRLoader.getResourceInputStream("image.jrxml")) {
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream));
}
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
MyBean myBean = new MyBean();

File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("smile.jpg").getFile());
myBean.setLogo(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));

params.put("mybean", myBean);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());

SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
File outputFile = new File("output.pdf");
try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(byteArrayOutputStream));
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();
    byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
}
```

The generated report looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't use the getInstance. I'll try, but I think it's OK. I try too to put directly the byte[] in the image element and works fine.